# echoing multiple image urls out of the db

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to echo out multiple image urls from one column from the database. My echo script which echo's out the numbers of images that is coming from the db

however it can't get the main image for each image out  from the folder only showing boxes that are equivalent to the db image paths this is my code.Thanks in Advance

Note:commas where used to seperate the images while inserting image path to the db

```
<?php
  $q="praise"; //Folder path
  $get_pro="SELECT * FROM `a`";

  $run_pro = mysqli_query($con, $get_pro);

  while($row_pro=mysqli_fetch_array($run_pro)){
       $a=$row_pro['q'];

       $str= $row_pro["image"];
       $array =  explode(',', $str);

       foreach ($array as $item) {

          echo "<img src=\"".$q."/".$item . "\" height=\"200\" width=\"200\"/>";   //only shows image boxes expecting images but calling from the folder is the problem
       }
  }
?>
```

Comment: @Filip Kováč  Thanks i have made the update was a mistake

Answer (score 1):

try this If your image has absolute path

```
   <?php
  $q="praise"; //Folder path
  $get_pro="SELECT * FROM `a`";

  $run_pro = mysqli_query($con, $get_pro);

  while($row_pro=mysqli_fetch_array($run_pro)){

     $a=$row_pro['q'];

     $str= $row_pro["image"];
     $array =  explode(',', $str);

     foreach ($array as $item) {

       // absolute path of the image
       echo "<img src='".$q.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$item."'  height='200' width='200'/>"; 
    }
 }

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you know you have `praise` use two times in source as $q and in $item ? Try to compare src of image with path to image on server.

Answer (score 0):

would you please try that

```
     <?php
      $q="praise"; //Folder path
      $get_pro="SELECT * FROM `a`";

      if($run_pro = mysqli_query($con, $get_pro)) {

      while($row_pro=mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_pro)){

       $a = $row_pro['q'];
       $str = $row_pro["image"];
       $array =  explode(',', $str);

     }
       foreach ($array as $item) {
?>
<img src="<?php echo $q."/".$item;  ?>" height="200" width="200" />
<?php
      }

      } else  {
         echo "error failed to run mysql query";
     }
     ?>
```